# Rails - how to pass data to controller without having it show in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have a controller action.

```
  def pending
    @current_item_id = params[:id]
    @pending_items = Item.pending.where("items.id != ?", @current_item_id) 
    @pending_item = @pending_items.offset(rand @pending_items.count).first
  end
```

When a user visits "/pending" they see the view generated by pending.html.erb which uses `@pending_item`.  There is a link on this page to "/pending" which should find another `@pending_item` that is not equal to the current `@pending_item` it so that there are no back to back repeats.

One way to do this (I believe) would be to pass the id of the current pending_item to the params with something like `pending_path(id: @pending_item.id)`.  But this would cause the url to look like "/pending?id=15".  Is this considered bad practice?

Is there a better way to do this so the url remains "/pending"?

Comment: You can use sessions to transport the @pending_item.id

Comment: why not `pending_path(other_pending_item)`?